# xhgui front-end malformed page rendering after installation

Tags: php, profiling

I have downloaded [xhgui](https://github.com/perftools/xhgui) after following steps in README.md ,i fortunately can profile my application,but xhgui front-end does not render well.I took two screenshots from first page of xhgui as follows :

[image]
[image]

I do not know why front-end does not rendered well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an [issue](https://github.com/perftools/xhgui/issues/130)  for this problem in `xhgui` Github repo,
i have answered there why this problem occurred.